# How do I calculate how many times something occurs in a 7 day period?

Tags: sql, sas

I have an Excel sheet of 1 million rows that span 12 months from January 2020-January 2021. I have to display all of the attributes for the output.

This is an example of the 2 attributes I'm looking at for the code, but there are 15 attributes in total:

```
Attribute: Subscriber_Number |   Date_Email_Sent 
       19202                     03Dec2020
       12829                     03Dec2020 
       13455                    05Dec2020
       13455                    05Dec2020
       13455                    02 Dec2020
       13455                    04 Dec2020
```

An email cannot be sent to a subscriber more than 3 times a week. If that happens, that would become an issue. My goal is to find subscribers who have been called more than 3 times a week. In the example data I gave, the code output should show that Subscriber 13455 was called 4 times in a week. The code output should NOT include 12829 because it just occurs one time.

This is a code that I tried:

```
PROC SQL; 
Select week (Date_Email_Sent, 'u') as weeknum, COUNT(Subscriber_Number) as per_week FROM Data; 
Where SubscriberNumber >2 
Group By week(Date_Email_Sent, 'U') 
quit;
```

I got a large results were detected line, so I discarded results. There shouldn't be that many times that an email was sent to a subscriber (<10,000 instances), so I'm sure that I wrote the code incorrectly.

Comment: It can easily be handled with analytical functions where you can use moving window with offset of 3 days and do count inside it, but as I could find they are not supported neither by `PROC SQL` nor by `PROC FEDSQL`. You may use correlated subquery in `SELECT` (reference the same table by id and filter by 3 days back relative to current row's date), but it is not very performant

Comment: If you're getting a lot of results, you may find it easier to view results by using the `noprint` option for `proc sql` and then creating a table rather than printing query result to the results window.  That would at least allow you to validate what you are seeing.  The syntax would be like:  `proc sql noprint;  create table want as select * from sashelp.class; quit;`

Comment: That ended up working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With standard sql, you can find those records using:

```
select Subscriber_Number, Date_Email_Sent
from Data
group by Subscriber_Number, Date_Email_Sent
having count(*) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want subscribers who received more than 3 emails in a calendar week, then the logic should look like this:

```
PROC SQL; 
    Select week(Date_Email_Sent, 'u') as weeknum, Subscriber_Number,  
           count(*) as per_week
    from Data; 
    Where SubscriberNumber >2 
    Group By week(Date_Email_Sent, 'U'), Subscriber_Number
    having count(*) > 3;
quit;
```